# c# Get database's columns max value with reference to another column

Tags: c#, database, entity

I have a database table name question , in that table , there is many columns but i would like to focus on this 3 columns : Activity , Task and QuestionNO

The problem is that i want to get the max value of the column QuestionNo in reference to Activity and Task. So If activity is 1 , task is 2 , questionNo starts from 1, 2 and so on , then when activiy is 1 , task is 3 , questionNo starts from 1, 2 and so on ... because i will be keep adding +1 value to the max value of the column QuestionNo , i want to start from 1 when its different activity and task.

The problems looks like this now in database:

```
  Activity   Task   QuestionNo
      1       2        1
      1       2        2
      1       2        3
      1       3        4
      1       3        5 
      2       1        6
```

i want it to be like :

```
  Activity   Task   QuestionNo
      1       2        1
      1       2        2
      1       2        3
      1       3        1  <---
      1       3        2  <---
      2       1        1  <---
```

For now my code to retrieve the max value of column QuestionNo is only:

```
 public int GetMaxValue()
    {
        int maxQNo = Convert.ToInt32(context.questions.Max(q => q.QuestionNo));
        return maxQNo+1;
    }
```

I am using entity framework. i want to know how to retrieve max value of column QuestionNo in reference to activity and task.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Where`

```
public int GetNextQuestionNo(int activity, int task)
{
    return context.questions
        .Where(q => q.Activity == activity && q.Task == task)
        .Max(q => q.QuestionNo) + 1;
}
```